# Use of Scenario outline in passing the scenario name as example

Tags: selenium, specflow

Can I use scenario outline concept in scenario name in Specflow so that I pass the scenario name in Example. For example if I want to run my scenario in three browsers IE, FF and chrome, I'll pass three examples.

I have tried it in Cucumber and it works, can I do it with Specflow in VS ?

Like

```
Scenario outline : <Scenario name>
steps 1
step 2
Examples:
|Scenario name|
|scenario 1 |
|scenario 2 |
|scenario 3 |
```

can I implement that ?

Comment: have you tried this? I don't know if it will work, though I expect as the gherkin parser is becoming more central, if this works in cucumber with the v3 parser, then it will work with specflow in 2.1, but the easiest will be to try this

Comment: Could you explain how to use v3 parser for this?

Comment: [This pull request](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/pull/576) updated specflow to the latest version of the gherkin parser, and I think this will be included in the 2.1 release. There is no way to 'use the v3 parser for this' other than updating to the new version (which I believe is still prerelease)