# Parameterised Scenario name in Cucumber Java

Tags: gherkin, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

This was a popular question, just curious whether any one found a solution for this.

I referred below links and couldn't find any real answer.

[Use of Scenario outline in passing the scenario name as example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36917437/use-of-scenario-outline-in-passing-the-scenario-name-as-example)

[How can i get cucumber scenario variables in title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50631176/how-can-i-get-cucumber-scenario-variables-in-title)

[Scenario outline with examples in title #267](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/issues/267)

My scenario is looks like below:

```
Scenario Outline: User login to <Scenario>

    Given the user "<User>" log in
    When user call "<URL>"
    Then the response should return the status code as "400" with error elements:
      | code                           | Message                         |
      | Profile Error                  | Incorrect user user entitlement |                                                

    Examples:
      | Scenario  | User       | URL           | 
      | Domain A  | TestUser1  | user/profile1 | 
      | Domain B  | TestUser2  | user/profile1 |
```

In the report I expect three separate results with corresponding scenario name from the `Example` data, but scenario name coming as empty in higher level in the report and the test result details level ONLY the first scenario name was showing which is `Domain A`. Not sure whether this is serenity reporting issue

```
User login to ""

    Given the user "{User}" log in
    When user call "{URL}"
    Then the response should return the status code as "400" with error elements:
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: This feature already exists. If your scenario outline has <parameters> then it will get replaced by Examples datatable iteration values. Please check if you’re using latest version of io.cucumber. Or please elaborate your question.

Comment: @BhuvaneshMani I added sample scenario to the question. I am using `io.cucumber:cucumber-core:2.4`. But in the report (`serenity`) I cannot see scenarios separately based on the scenario name.

Comment: Bhuvanesh's answer works on the cucumber java 7.13.0.